# Trying to understand and implement Symfony 3 Caching for Framework and Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

We have a running application based on Symfony 3.2 (started with Symfony 2.3 back then) and Doctrine ORM 2.5 and it's awesome how things have evolved.

I read a lot about the new Symfony Cache component, the up's and down's of APC and APCU, opcache, the pull requests for chaching in Symfony etc... but to be very honest this time you lost me a bit.

So I kindly ask whether one can support me in 1) understanding and 2) implementing caching for a "standard" Symfony/Doctrine application in production.

**Prerequisites/Assumptions**

1) **opcache** should be enabled and active and cache anything bytecode related.

2) I currently don't have any requirement to cache my own app stuff. It's all about the framework caching like annotations, class maps, validations, ORM metadata etc.

2) Most developers don't want to deal with more than one caching provider, so be it APCu, xcache, redis, memcache or anything else. There might be very good reasons to have different ones for different tasks but let's stick to one to keep it simple.

**Caching Options in a "standard" Symfony/Doctrine application in prod mode**

***1) Class Loading***

We still have ApcClassLoader in place in `app.php`:

```
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';

$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader('arcsf2', $loader);
$apcLoader->register(true);
$loader->unregister();

require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
```

There are only two options Symfony built-in to my understanding, ApcClassLoader and XcacheClassLoader. So this might be contradicting assumption 2 above.

*Question:*

Is it still needed/required/performing significantly better to have this caching ClassLoaders in place?

Or is it enough to use the standard app.php nowadays?

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
```

***2) Validation Caching***

We still have this in our `config_prod.yml`:

```
framework:
validation:
    cache: validator.mapping.cache.doctrine.apc
```

*Question:*

To be very honest I have no idea, whether this is still valid with Symfony 3.2 and the new Cache component. And how to change it to a different Cache Provider if required. How could I change it to be 'up-to-date' with Symfony 3.2 Cache?

***3) Doctrine Caching:***

More or less the same question applies to the doctrine orm section in `config_prod.yml`:

```
doctrine:
orm:
    metadata_cache_driver: apc
    result_cache_driver: apc
    query_cache_driver: apc
```

*Question*:

Is this still the way to go? How to change this use the new Symfony Cache component - can this be done anyway?

***4) New Options?***

What about the new? options? of setting in `config_prod.yml`:

```
framework:
cache:
    app: cache.adapter.someProviderOrPool
    system: cache.adapter.someProviderOrPool
```

*Question*:

What kind of information is cached here, by whom and is this somehow replacing/extending some of the topics above?

**To sum it up:**

I want to basically change all my prod configs to be complient with Symfony 3.2 and I want to use redis for caching (replacing apc) wherever possible but I have absolutely no idea how and where to start.

****EDIT****

As well in this context how do Symfony Cache Component and DoctrineCacheBundle play together? Replacing? Adding up? Building Upon? Working together? Conflicting? Not Comparable?

Comment: Why the downvote? Or at least can a downvoter shortly comment on how to improve the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit: Everything written here has been merged into Symfony's official documentation since then. [You may want to check the up-to-date documentation instead](https://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html)*

**Use the OPcache byte code cache**

OPcache stores the compiled PHP files to avoid having to recompile them for every request. There are some byte code caches available, but as of PHP 5.5, PHP comes with OPcache built-in. For older versions, the most widely used byte code cache is APC.

**Configure OPcache for maximum performance**

The default OPcache configuration is not suited for Symfony application, so it's recommended to change these settings as follows:

```
; php.ini

; maximum memory that OPcache can use to store compiled PHP files
opcache.memory_consumption=256M

; maximum number of files that can be stored in the cache
opcache.max_accelerated_files=20000
```

**Don't check PHP timestamps**

In production servers, PHP files should never change, unless a new application version is deployed. However, by default OPcache checks if cached files have changed their contents since caching them. This check introduces some overhead that can be avoided as follows:

```
; php.ini

; after each deploy, call `opcache_reset()` or restart the web server
; to empty the cache and regenerate the cached files. Otherwise you won't
; see the updates made in the application
opcache.validate_timestamps=0
```

**Note**

The OPcache is different for the web server and the command console. You cannot clear the web server OPcache by executing some command in your terminal. You either need to restart the web server or call the opcache_reset() function via the web server (i.e. by having this in a script that you execute over the web).

**Configure the PHP realpath Cache**

When a relative path is transformed into its real and absolute path, PHP caches the result to improve performance. The default config of this cache is not suited for applications that open many PHP files, such as Symfony. It's recommended to change these settings as follows:

```
; php.ini

; maximum memory allocated to store the results
realpath_cache_size=4096K

; save the results for 10 minutes (600 seconds)
realpath_cache_ttl=600
```

**Configure the PHP realpath Cache**

PHP uses an internal cache to store the result of mapping file paths to their real and absolute file system paths. This increases the performance for applications like Symfony that open many PHP files, especially on Windows systems.

By default, PHP sets a realpath_cache_size of 16K which is too low for Symfony. Consider updating this value at least to 4096K. In addition, cached paths are only stored for 120 seconds by default. Consider updating this value too using the `realpath_cache_ttl` option:

```
; php.ini

realpath_cache_size=4096K
realpath_cache_ttl=600
```

**Optimize Composer Autoloader**

The class loader used while developing the application is optimized to find new and changed classes. In production servers, PHP files should never change, unless a new application version is deployed. That's why you can use Composer's autoloader optimization to scan the entire application once and build a "class map", which is a big array of the locations of all the classes and it's stored in *vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php*.

Execute this command to generate the class map at install time (and thus make it part of your deployment process too):

```
$ composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --classmap-authoritative --apcu-autoloader
```

`--no-dev` Excludes the classes that are only needed in the development environment (e.g. tests).

`--optimize-autoloader` Dumps every PSR-0 and PSR-4 compatible class used in your application.

`--classmap-authoritative` Prevents Composer from scanning the file system for classes that are not found in the class map.

`--apcu-autoloader` You need to install APCu PHP extension to use this option. It will cache the classmap in APCu. It won't generate the classmap though, so you need to always use it with `--optimize-autoloader`

**Tip**

If your production server still uses the legacy APC PHP extension instead of OPcache, install the APCu Polyfill component in your application to enable compatibility with APCu PHP functions and unlock support for advanced Symfony features, such as the APCu Cache adapter.

**Note**

When using the APCu autoloader, if you add new classes, they will be found automatically and everything will work the same as before (i.e. no reason to "clear" the cache). However, if you change the location of a particular namespace or prefix, you'll need to flush your APCu cache. Otherwise, the autoloader will still be looking at the old location for all classes inside that namespace.